# In Polygon transaction ID of Sync-State transactions does not match Keccak-256(RLP(nonce,gasPrice,gasLimit,to,value,data,v,r,s)

Tags: polygon, hash

Polygon has special “Sync-State” transactions added to the blocks https://polygonscan.com/address/0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 .
Transaction hash returned by eth_getBlockByNumber does not match Keccak-256(RLP(nonce,gasPrice,gasLimit,to,value,data,v,r,s).

Do any of you have any insight on this?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is at most 1 state-sync transaction in one block.
Polygon's geth clone bor computed the hash using the block-number, block-hash.

Concrete algorithm to compute hash is Keccak256(“matic-bor-receipt-” + block-number + block-hash).

Polygon team responded to my question at https://github.com/maticnetwork/bor/issues/411